# SQL 2003 Error - System.ArgumentException: Column 'Quantity' does not belong to table 1

Tags: sql-server

I'm using Visual Studio to build a piece of software that connects to my MSSQL 2003 Server. I am trying to Pull data from a table in order to use it in a stored procedure and am receiving the following error.

System.ArgumentException: Column 'Quantity' does not belong to table TMS_Campaign.

I have double checked that the column name is spelt correctly and that the case is correct. I have also tried to do an IISRESET.exe and simply rebooting the machine at the recommendation from some other post.

```
Sub SendMail()
    Dim SQL As String
    Dim oDS As New Data.DataSet
    Dim oDT As New Data.DataTable
    Dim ServerID As Integer = GetServerID()


    SQL = "exec sp_Check " & ServerID
    oDT = GetRS(SQL)

    If oDT.Rows.Count = 0 Then
        'if there is NO item set status = Ready and EXIT
        SQL = "UPDATE TMS_Server" & vbCrLf &
                 "SET StatusID = 3," & vbCrLf &
                 "StatusDateTime = GetDate()" & vbCrLf &
                 "WHERE SID = " & ServerID
        AddLineToLog("No Schedule - " & Now)
        Application.DoEvents()
        Wait(5)
    Else
        'set IDs
        G.MID = oDT.Rows(0)("MID")
        G.CID = oDT.Rows(0)("CID")
        G.LID = oDT.Rows(0)("LID")
        G.SFID = oDT.Rows(0)("SFID")
        G.LastID = oDT.Rows(0)("LastID")
        G.BatchSize = oDT.Rows(0)("BatchSize")
        G.Quantity = oDT.Rows(0)("Quantity")

        'GET LIST

        ExecuteSQL("sp_GetOrderID_V4 " & G.LID & "," & G.MID & "," & G.Quantity)
```

EDIT - Code from comment:

```
CREATE proc sp_CheckForCampaign 
@ServerID int as 
 SELECT TOP 1 MID, L.LID, L.AKID, L.AKLevel, C.CID, C.Warm, SFID, LaunchDateTime, LastID, BatchSize, BatchInterval 
FROM TMS_Mailings M 
INNER JOIN TMS_Campaign C ON M.CID = C.CID 
INNER JOIN TMS_Server S ON M.SID = S.SID 
INNER JOIN TMS_List L ON M.LID = L.LID 
WHERE LaunchDateTime < GetDate() 
AND M.SID = @ServerID 
AND M.StatusID IN (1,2) -- Scheduled, Mailing 
ORDER BY LaunchDateTime 
GO
```

Comment: The code you posted does not reference TMS_Campaign.   Can you post that code?   I assume it's in sp_GetOrderID_V4.   Or actually, maybe it's in sp_Check

Comment: @TabAlleman
`CREATE    proc sp_CheckForCampaign
@ServerID int
as <br/>
SELECT TOP 1
MID,
L.LID,
L.AKID,
L.AKLevel,
C.CID,
C.Warm,
SFID,
LaunchDateTime,
LastID,
BatchSize,
BatchInterval
FROM TMS_Mailings M
INNER JOIN TMS_Campaign C
 ON M.CID = C.CID <br/>
INNER JOIN TMS_Server S <br/>
 ON M.SID = S.SID
INNER JOIN TMS_List L
 ON M.LID = L.LID
WHERE LaunchDateTime < GetDate()
AND M.SID = @ServerID
AND M.StatusID IN (1,2) -- Scheduled, Mailing
ORDER BY LaunchDateTime
GO`

Comment: Your sendmail proc calls sp_Check, but you have posted code for sp_CheckForCampaign.   So I doubt it's relevant.   Especially since the code you posted doesn't reference a "Quantity" column.

Comment: @TabAlleman
Sorry about that. sp_Check & sp_CheckForCampaign are identical Stored Procedures(one for testing/development and one for the live software). I added Quantity to both Stored Procedures. This appears to be working now. Thank you for your assistance.